# Sharing binary folders in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

For a long time i have tried to work out the best way to access certain site files which i don't wish to be apart of a project or to ease integration with multiple developers (and talents, e.g. designers) on a single project.

A lot of sites i have created have had folders with large amounts of images and other binary files which i have not wanted to include in a visual studio project and/or source control mainly due to the constant updating of their contents. I have seen some people use virtual directories however there is no way to use virtual directories if you are using visual studio's built in web server.

As far as i see it, ideally, folders containing binaries could be located on a central server and mapped to a project. Alernatively i have considered creating separate sub-domains for each project with which all images / binaries can be refereced via, e.g. `http://project.client.customer.com/images`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should really be source controlled like everything else.  If you use Subversion you could have them stored in a different repository and included as an [svn-external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) on your main project repository if you didn't want them cluttering up your main repo.  I'm sure other source control solutions offer similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You really ought to keep them in source control. If you're using Subversion, as Beepcake says, you can use svn:externals to share the files between different projects.

Alternatively, you could have a custom build action that fetches the latest copy of the shared files from wherever you keep them. We do this in a variety of ways -- either we issue an "svn checkout" for a subdirectory (but svn:externals would work for this), or we do a "wget ..." to grab the output from the last successful build of another project (we use TeamCity for continuous integration, and it makes "artifacts" available over HTTP).

Answer (score 1):

Images and other binaries should be in source control just like your code files.  Especially since they are changing often.

That said, there is absolutely no harm in setting up a different project that only contains your binary files; and having it on a different deployment schedule.

Comment: Unfortunately some projects require hundreds of images for CSS, general site images and flash then there can be hundreds of PDF's, Docs which are needed for the site. Including them can mean it takes ages to load a project and sync it. If your unlucky enough to use VSS then this is far more painful.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using "web projects" with VSS.  If you were using "Web Application Projects" then this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: thanks for your response, im not sure why using "web application projects" would resolve this. Could you clarify please? If binaries are held in a seperate project then how would the file paths work?

Comment: When a web project solution loads it forces a refresh on all of the sub folders.  This takes some time.  A web app stores the list of files that make up the application in the project file; which is a lot faster to load.